# How to have one strategy in strategy pattern return more than one value

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have a strategy pattern implemented. One of the strategies is supposed to return 2 values while rest of them returns 1 value. I am currently using **out param** in the interface method for the sake of it being available for one strategy that sets this value and making it null for all other strategies as in the below example

I would like to know if there is a better way of having that one strategy return multiple values without making all other strategies deal with this out param(even though they are all going to set it null)
Eg:

```
public interface IContributionStrategy
{
    decimal (decimal configuredAmt, out decimal? recurrent);
}
public class Strategy1 : IContributionStrategy
{
  public Strategy1 (int param1)
  {
    this.Param = param1;
  }
  public decimal Calculate(decimal amt, out decimal? recurrent)
  {
     recurrent = somevalue;
     //some logic that uses amt and this.Param and performs calc
     return calculatedLogic;
  }
public class Strategy2 : IContributionStrategy
{
  public decimal Calculate(decimal amt, out decimal? recurrent)
  {
     recurrent = null; //having to set this to null only because its in the Calculate() in the interface and this strategy is not using the recurrent value.
     //some logic that uses amt and performs calc
     return calculatedLogic;
  }
}
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<decimal?>` as the return type perhaps?

Comment: Or a class that has two properties in it (for the two values)?

Comment: If you have many strategies that return one value, and a single one that should return multiple values, it doesn't sounds like the latter belongs in the same place.  How are they used?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a class that contains both.

```
public class CalculateResult {
    decimal amount {get;set}
    decimal? recurrent {get;set}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have two strong alternative signatures to consider:

(1)

```
IEnumerable<decimal> Calculate(decimal configuredAmt);
```

(2)

```
decimal Calculate(decimal configuredAmt, Action<decimal> extra);
```

You'd implement these like this:

(1)

```
public IEnumerable<decimal> Calculate(decimal amt)
{
    yield return 1m;
    yield return 42m;
    yield return 2m;
}
```

(2)

```
public decimal Calculate(decimal amt, Action<decimal> extra)
{
    extra(1m);
    extra(42m);
    return 2m;
}
```

This second option might get used like this:

```
var s = new Strategy1();
var extras = new List<decimal>();
decimal r = s.Calculate(1m, x => extras.Add(x));
```

The result is that `r == 2m` & `extras` contains `1m` & `42m`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning primitive data type I would suggest you to return a user defined data type (like class, structure) containing all the required information as properties.

```
class result
{
   decimal result1;
   decimal? result2;
   .......
}
```